# how to delete created server WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am working on docker images

setting up in docker file ...

```
# - Liberty installation of required features
RUN /opt/wlp/bin/featureManager install adminCenter-1.0 localConnector-1.0 jaxrs-1.1 jsp-2.2 jdbc-4.0 jndi-1.0 cdi-1.0 servlet-3.0 beanValidation-1.0 --when-file-exists=ignore --acceptLicense

RUN /opt/wlp/bin/server create my-server
...
```

but getting error

```
CWWKE0005E: The runtime environment could not be launched.
CWWKE0045E: It was not possible to create the server called cca-dist-d because the server directory /srv/www/servers/my-server already exists.
ERROR: Service 'appserver' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /opt/wlp/bin/server create my-server' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Is there way to remove such server before creation or any suggestions?

just for notice that rm -R does not work :-(

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'rm -R  /opt/wlp/bin/server/my-server'
---> Running in 83f*****bd
rm: cannot remove '/opt/wlp/bin/server/my-server': Not a directory
```

Comment: You're trying to remove an unrelated directory under bin/ that doesn't exist, and you omitted -f from your rm command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Liberty profile server deletion, it is as simple as to delete the entire directory. For example

> rm -R WLP_HOME/usr/servers/my-server

Now about your error message, you should check why the server exist. Sounds like you have a problem in your setup.

And if you want to delete the `my-server` anyway, then you should remove the right directory. In your case:

> rm -R /srv/www/servers/my-server

The servers are created into `servers directory` from `WLP_USER_DIR` environment. And the variable can be used to specify an alternate location for `${wlp.user.dir}`. If this is specified, the runtime will look for shared resources and server definitions in the specified directory. Check `server start script` or `README file` for more information about the different environment variables.

In your case it seems that the WLP_USER_DIR is `/srv/www/`

Comment: thank you @MrSimpleMind for answer, last one with rm -R works. Just small question: first 'del' command is for /opt/wlp/bin/server?

Comment: I mean del (from windows delete), the right should be in windows rmdir /Q /S dir-name... anyway, the thing you should know is that the server is located in your wlp_user_dir which in your case is /srv/www .. see added info.